# Android: Need receive data back from Facebook App Link host api with Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm developing an native only application, it has a Facebook sharing feature that share a RSS url. When use click on a post/story I would like Facebook to open my app and pass some data to open the right view for best user experience.

I have read and created an app link and get the canonical_url: https://fb.me/xxx as the tutorial here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api

My share dialog:

```
FacebookDialog dialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
                .setLink(link)
                .setName(caption)
                .setCaption(caption)
                .setDescription(description)
                .setPicture(imageUrl)
                .setApplicationName(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();
        mUiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(dialog.present());
```

If I pass the `link` param is the web url, for example http://google.com/..., when I click on the shared story Facebook open the browser to load that url.

If I pass the `link` param is the canonical_url: https://fb.me/xxx, Facebook open my app directly and the received data from Facebook are:

```
Bundle[{extras=Bundle[{fb_expires_in=86400, fb_app_id=<app id>, fb_access_token=<access token>}], target_url=https://fb.me/xxx, referer_app_link=Bundle[{package=com.facebook.katana, url=fb:///, app_name=Facebook}]}]
```

What should I do to get the RSS url back from Facebook after use click on the shared story?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just put the data after the canonical_url so when I got it back from Facebook deep linking, parse the url to receive data back, for example
     https://fb.me/xxx?data=xyz&foo=bar

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the canonical id and canonical url by sample coding?

Comment: @Nas you can do it using applink host api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api

Comment: I already go through the link and posted a question. I couldn't get clear idea on that. Can you please give me sample piece of code. This is my que link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830770/how-can-i-get-canonical-url-from-facebook-graph-api-in-android. Please reply on that. I ll accept if it might be helpful for me.