# How can i get canonical url from facebook graph api in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, canonical-link

Am trying to implement deep link on Facebook sharing in my android applcation. That deep link is only for mobile and not for webpage. So according to the facebook documentation [Link1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content#hosting-api) [Link2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api#android) am going through Link2. The following should be called to get id of canonical url.  This canonical url will be set as a link on Facebook sharing.

To get canonical id

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/app/app_link_hosts \
-F access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-F name="Android App Link Object Example" \
-F android=' [
    {
      "url" : "sharesample://story/1234",
      "package" : "com.facebook.samples.sharesample",
      "app_name" : "ShareSample",
    },
  ]' \
-F web=' {
    "should_fallback" : false,
  }'
```

To get canonical url from canonical id

```
curl -G https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_LINK_HOST_ID \
-d access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d fields=canonical_url \
-d pretty=true
```

I don't know how to call this and i don't know the terms **app_link_hosts**, **Android App Link Object Example**, **YOUR_APP_LINK_HOST_ID** here actually means. Can anyone explain how to call this with example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. app_link_hosts is part of the actual graph path for the request, so don't change it, and just use it as is (/app/app_link_hosts is the full path).
2. "Android App Link Object Example" is the name of the url you're creating. It's for your benefit only, and is not really used for anything, so you can put anything you'd like there (I would keep it a human readable string).
3. "YOUR_APP_LINK_HOST_ID" is the result from the first curl command. The first curl command will return you a string ID, and you use that in the second command to get the canonical url (that you can use to share).

Comment: Thank you ming li. Am clear with the params. Can you please post tell me how to call this curl command with bundle(url,package,app_name). Can you please post sample of code snippets? Might very helpful.

Comment: You wouldn't call it with a bundle, it's only meant to be called from the command line or from the server side (which is why it needs an app access token).

Comment: I don't know how to call it from command line or from server side I don't have that much of knowledge on this other than Android. Please can you suggest me how to do this with any example or any tutorial you know. I need proper procedure to do this.

Comment: Hi @Nas, If you use MAC pc, just edit the command and paste it to the Terminal. Curl already exist in MAC environment. If you use Windows pc, install [Cywin](https://cygwin.com/install.html)  and run the command in Cywin window.