# get canonical url for android from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate facebook sdk in my android app. I want to use the deep link functionality for which i need a canonical url. I am not able to get the canonical url from api calls. I saw this question [on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830770/how-can-i-get-canonical-url-from-facebook-graph-api-in-android)
When I used the command

```
curl -G https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_LINK_HOST_ID \
-d access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d fields=canonical_url \
-d pretty=true
```

I got this error

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: YOUR_APP_LINK_HOST_ID -d",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 803
>      }
>   }curl: (6) Could not resolve host: access_token="APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"

Note: i replaced the original app access token with "APP_ACCESS_TOKEN".

Comment: You did replace the text `YOUR_APP_LINK_HOST_ID` with an actual app-link host id though, right …?

Comment: yes. all values were real in the command. can't post them here though.

Comment: `{   "error": {      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (canonical_url) on node type (Application)",      "type": "OAuthException",      "code": 100   }`
Now Iam getting this error

Comment: _“on node type (Application)”_ – that sounds like you did not use an app link id, but put your application id after `https://graph.facebook.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the command to work. I had to create the canonical url using the GUI at this [link](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fquickstarts%2F%3Fplatform%3Dapp-links-host&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHwrBsW2y2e4r4-bfw5-73s1ZjWgg).